# SDL2 enum <unnamed>::SDL_[key] forces out of bounds exception

Tags: c++, exception, opengl, keycode, sdl-2

I've written a small opengl application in c++ using SDL2 for window creation and input handling.

Now I have arrays of booleans which says, whether the appropriate key is pressed or not.

```
static const int NUM_KEYS = 512;

static bool Inputs[NUM_KEYS];
static bool DownKeys[NUM_KEYS];
static bool UpKeys[NUM_KEYS];
```

My input update method looks like this:

```
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYS; i++)
    {
        g_DownKeys[i] = false;
        g_UpKeys[i] = false;
    }

while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
{
    if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        m_isClosed = true;
    }

    switch(e.type) 
    {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            g_DownKeys[e.key.keysym.sym] = true;
            g_Inputs[e.key.keysym.sym] = true;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            g_UpKeys[e.key.keysym.sym] = true;
            g_Inputs[e.key.keysym.sym] = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

if(g_Inputs[SDLK_w])
{
     //this works just fine, because SDLK_w = 119
}
if(g_Inputs[SDLK_UP]) 
{
     //this crashes the program, because SDLK_UP = 1073741906
}
```

I also have found a list of each key with its keycode here:
http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDLKeycodeLookup

As you can see I can only use keys on keyboard, which have maximum keycode of 127 (decimal).

I also noticed that SDL2 uses an enumeration for the keys, so when I hover my cursor over `SDLK_UP` Visual Studio shows: `enum <unnamed>::SDLK_UP = 1073741906`, but the correct way is this: `enum SDLKey::SDLK_UP = 1073741906`.
So, there is SDLKey missing somewhere.

I think my input handling is OK.
How can I solve the problem with the index out of bounds exception?
I think therefore I have to solve the issue with the SDLKey enum.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if your arrays have 512 elemnts, and then you find out that the value of `SDLK_UP` is 1073741906, you shouldn't be surprised about "index out of bound" exceptions, right? :)

SDL2 introduced a distinction between 'keycodes' and 'scancodes'.

- A scancode represent a physical key on a keyboard. They are derived from the USB keyboard specification.
- A keycode represents the glyph that's printed on the keyboard. The keycode is normally the Unicode code of the character that's printed on the key, but special very huge values are used for non-character keys such as arrow keys.

There's more detailed information [on the SDL wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryKeyboard).

The way your code is written indicates that you want to use scancodes. So, first:

```
static const int NUM_KEYS = SDL_NUM_SCANCODES;
```

Then replace every occurence of `keysym.sym` with

```
keysym.scancode
```

And finally use the [SDL_Scancode constants](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Scancode):

```
SDL_SCANCODE_W
SDL_SCANCODE_UP
etc.
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by using `SDL1.2` instead of `SDL2`.

1. Delete initial files `SDL2.lib`, `SDL2main.lib` [,SDL2test.lib] from
   your project.
2. Replace them with `SDL.lib` and `SDLmain.lib`.
3. Delete `SDL2.dll` from your project.
4. Replace it with `SDL.dll`

Now you set up SDL1.2.

- You now need to fix additional lib directories in your linker
  settings and you also have to rewrite the code for creating a window
  (e.g. `SDL_Surface` instead of `SDL_Window`, etc...).

When you are using SDL1.2 you can find the missing `enum SDL_Key` inside `SDL_keysym.h`.

Comment: I wouldn't consider using SDL1.2 an answer, it is more a workaround.